# Cauchy Integral if f is R-differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if a function is $R$-differentiable in a neigborhood of a point $ a\in C$ then

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon}f(z)dz=2\pi i \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f(a)$$

I approached this problem by expressing $f(z)$ as follows:

$$f(z)= f(a) + {\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}(a)(z-a) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}(a)(\overline{z}-\overline{a}) + o(|z-a|)$$

The problem is where to continue from there. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You should better write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a)\cdot (z-a)$ or something similar (and analogous for the other Wirtinger derivative), as is it looks like $z-a$ resp. $\overline{z} - \overline{a}$ are the points where they should be evaluated. What do you get if you plug in that representation, and evaluate the integral for each term as best you can?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I am a little bit confused. I just made the corrections as stated. Could you kindly explain that one more time?

Comment: Can you compute $$\int_{\lvert z-a\rvert =  \epsilon} f(a)\,dz,\quad \int_{\lvert z-a\rvert = \epsilon} (z-a)\,dz,\quad \int_{\lvert z-a\rvert} (\overline{z} - \overline{a})\,dz\,?$$ And by the way, the last term ought to be $o(\lvert z-a\rvert)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, pardon if I appear naive. But I am struggling with such computations. Please how do I go about it?

Comment: With a holomorphic integrand, you typically use Cauchy's integral theorem or integral formula. Otherwise, if you have no good idea, take a parametrisation of the curve and look what that gives. In this case, that suffices.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I did try it out. But is it okay to write: $$\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}(a)(z-a)dz={\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}(a)\int_{|z-a|=\epsilon}(z-a)dz$$

Comment: Yes, it's okay to pull $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(a)$ out of the integral, because that's just a constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer, awesome! So the first two terms of $f(z)$ cancels out right? Including $o(|z-a|)$ goes to zero. And what is the expansion for $f(z)$ ( is a formula or Taylor series expansion) called?

Comment: It's the first order Taylor expansion of $f$. One often says "in complex form" when writing Taylor expansions using the Wirtinger derivatives.